# Offset Anti-dependence

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

[image]

After the rescheduling,
S.D 0(R1),F4 changed to S.D 8(R1), F4.

It says "altered offset 0=>8 when moved DADDUI"

Can any one explain more about this?
I am not sure why the offset is changed from 0 to 8..

Comment: If you decrement your pointer before the store, the store-address needs a different offset.  The comment seems pretty useless and obvious as a comment.  It would be ok in a changelog (commit message) for the change, but talking about the old loop doesn't make sense in comments on the new loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes Beside all of stuffs, could you explain why the offset is changed from 0 to 8? Is it because R1 is decremented by 8 so I put 8 instead of 0?

Comment: yes, of course.  It balances the change from doing R1-=8 before the store, like I said in my first sentence.

Comment: @PeterCordes Just one more thing. If I change DADDUI R1,R1,-8 to DADDUI R1,R1,20 then the S.D 8(R1),F4 should change to  S.D 20(R1),F4. Am I doing it right?